# How to make Joomla SEBLOD RTL?

Tags: php, templates, joomla, right-to-left, overriding

I'm using Joomla 3.1.1. and I came accross a problem while using SEBLOD extention.

Whate PHP code do I have to use (template override) in order to make my website RTL ?

Take this code for example, what do I need to use in order to make it RTL ?

websitename/templates/**seb_one**/positions/mycontentname/content/**mainbody.php**:

```
<?php 
// No Direct Access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
?>
<p><?php echo $cck->renderField('test'); ?></p>
```

Comment: Have you done any research on RTL support for Joomla? Cause there IS documentation on it for templates

Comment: Ofer, RTL support is done using the presentation layer, namely CSS. I do not know Seblod, but normally, it is up to your template to include the appropriate styling. Usually, there is an override sheet(s) for RTL, or an RTL sheet replaces the original one. I hope that the designers of this component had RTL support in mind, otherwise this could require some work.